# How to get individual File Size from cwd in Python

Tags: python, python-3.7

still very new to programming and learning the basics, any help is greatly appreciated.

```
import os

path = os.getcwd()
print(os.listdir(path))
os.path.getsize(path)
print(os.path.getsize(path))
```

When I run the above program I get this output:

```
['Lab3_Exercise1.py', 'Lab3_Exercise2.py', 'Lab3_Exercise4.py', 'Lab3_Exercose3.py']
4096
```

How would I go about separating out each file individually in the output rather than just getting a total file size? Code should include only the `import os` module if possible and be universal where it could tell any user each individual file size of their current working directory. Thank you for the help.

Output should be similar to:

```
file: Lab3_Exercise1.py size:
file: Lab3_Exercise2.py size:
file: Lab3_Exercise3.py size:
file: Lab3_Exercise4.py size:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the other answers work, they also include directories in the list of "files". If you want to exclude them you can use `os.path.isfile(f)` like this:

```
import os

path = os.getcwd()
files = [f for f in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isfile(f)]
for f in  files:
    print(f, "-", os.path.getsize(f))
```

which outputs:

```
comb.py - 228
list_ex.py - 348
so_cwd_size.py - 145
matrix_test.py - 173
thread_test.py - 847
```

Answer (score 1):

This code should do what is expected:

```
path = os.getcwd()
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    print(filename, int(os.path.getsize(filename)))
```

The output is:

```
('test.py', 215)
('test.sh', 51)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can prepare dictionary with {filename: filesize} like this:

```
import os

path = os.getcwd()
listfiles = os.listdir(path)

{f:os.path.getsize(f) for f in listfiles}
```

Output something like this

```
Out[1]:
{'GBPCAD.csv': 1946,
 'data3.xlsx': 8892,
 'sandbox2.ipynb': 41218,
 'Untitled1.ipynb': 11984,
 'res.csv': 106}
```

does it desire result?